# Select data one by one from table and data need to repeat custom number of times

Tags: sql-server-2005, select

I have table data like

```
data1
data2
data3
data4
```

and I need to select these rows like this:

```
data1
data1
data1
data1
data2
data2
data2
data3
data3
```

and how to perform this in SQL Server 2005?

Comment: What is the need for this? Your application will need to pass in information such as `4,data1`, `4,data2`, `1,data3` to tell SQL Server how many rows to return. So  it might as well not bother involving SQL Server at all and just create the collection itself.

Comment: @Martin Smith you got the point...thats what i want and please explain with example how to do it? and i need the output must single table datas...that is important

Comment: Please don't delete your questions and re-ask. People will still reply to the original one even if it's several hours old.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't explained why you need SQL Server to do this multiplying out of rows rather than your application. You are quite possibly asking the wrong question.

You can do this With an auxiliary table of numbers though.

```
CREATE TABLE Numbers (N INT PRIMARY KEY)

INSERT INTO Numbers
SELECT TOP 1000000 ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 0))
FROM master..spt_values v1, master..spt_values v2
```

and then

```
SELECT T.YourColumn
FROM   YourTable T
       INNER JOIN Numbers N
         ON ( T.YourColumn = 'data1' AND N.N <= 4 )
             OR ( T.YourColumn = 'data2' AND N.N <= 4 )
             OR ( T.YourColumn = 'data3' AND N.N <= 1 )
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention that....these nooftimes will send from application and the server need to give output like the above....is your current answer will work for that? need to get nooftimes from application...please help

Comment: @SureshE - Well your application would need to generate a parameterised version of the query above with as many `OR` conditions as required or use one of the methods in [Arrays and Lists in SQL Server 2005](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2005.html) to pass in these values. As I've already commented I don't see why you are trying to do this in SQL at all. You should probably ask a question on StackOverflow (as off topic here) as to how to achieve what ever it is you are trying to do at the application level.